# How do I reload the page without the query parameters?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I want to reload `www.domain.com/abc?num=4`

But I want to reload `www.domain.com/abc` ONLY (without everything after the question mark)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
window.location = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
```

Comment: Better: `window.location = window.location.pathname`

Comment: @Noyo actually this answer works better with modern frameworks that use # to denote views and paths ( angular, GWT ).  pathname ignores the #

Comment: You make a good point, @qbert65536, but this is still better (and avoids function calls): `window.location = window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;`

Comment: It's worth noting that `window.location = window.location.pathname` isn't valid TypeScript syntax. You need to use `window.location.href = window.location.pathname`.

Answer (score 30):

There are a few ways to go about it:

```
window.location = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
```

Or, alternatively:

```
window.location = window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: I don't really understand what it means, but it's worth reading before copy-pasting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLUtils.pathname

Answer (score 22):

This is the best and easiest way,

```
// similar to HTTP redirect
window.location.replace(location.pathname);
```

Comment: In my case, used this for reload the app: 
const tmpLocation = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/';
window.location.replace(tmpLocation);

Comment: Or `location.replace(location.pathname);` for short.

Answer (score 9):

I typically try to avoid making unnecessary function calls whenever I can, especially when the information I need is already provided to me by the DOM. That said, here is probably objectively the best solution:

```js
window.location = window.location.pathname + window.location.hash;
```

As pointed out in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241851/in-javascript-how-do-i-reload-the-page-without-the-query-parameters/7241874?noredirect=1#comment52455041_7241874) by user [qbert65536](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1337379/qbert65536), there are many popular modern frameworks that use the hash to denote views and paths, which is why using `window.location.pathname` alone is not enough.

Answer (score 5):

Try this Javascript:

```
location = location.pathname;
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the user is pressing a button to make this refresh happen. If the button is inside a form element  make sure the button type is set to "button" (example below):

```
<button type='button' id='mybutton'>Button Name</button>
```

if the type is **not** set then it will default to type='submit' and will act as a form submit button and thus give you all the extra parameters in the url when reloaded.

Then after that it is a simple javascript refresh call:

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: calling reload triggers a browser refresh which can have the effect of IE complaining about resending a previous form submission. I'd prefer against this for UI/UX concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Plain and simple, just tested:

```
window.location.href = location.pathname;
```

Comment: window.location will update the url without navigating. the href forces the page to load

Answer (score 1):

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location#Example_5_Send_a_string_of_data_to_the_server_by_modifying_the_search_property)

```js
location.search = '';
```

Or using relative URL, but this will leave the `?` in the URL
([Reference RFC1808](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808))

```html
<a href="?">
```

```js
// JavaScript
location = '?';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
top.location.href = top.location.protocol+top.location.host+top.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.location = String(document.location).replace(/\?.*$/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use document.URL and split function to the url you want to load and use the method window.location.href to load the page

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url = 'www.domain.com/abc?num=4';
alert(url.split('?')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url="www.domain.com/abc?num=4";
window.location.href=url.replace(/^([^\?]+)(\??.*)$/gi,"$1");
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't really understand your question, but maybe this will help you:

```
<input type="button" value="Reload Page" onClick="window.location.href=www.domain.com/abc">
```