# A relative url value for href attribute

Tags: html, anchor, href

Let's say currently I'm at `www.example.com/category1/?page2`, I want to put an anchor tag in the html which could redirect me to `www.example.com/category1`. I tried to use `href='/'` but it will take me to `www.example.com` instead of `www.example.com/category1`. I also tried to use `href=" "` but it just refresh the current page. So how should I specify the href attribute of the anchor tag?

Comment: `href="?"` would be functionally equal, if you don't mind a trailing `?`.

Answer (score 2):

if you use a relative url, it's always relative to the top level, not whatever level you're at. So if you want to be at `www.example.com/category1`, use `/category1`

EDIT: misunderstood your question. If you want to just clear get params from your url, look at similar questions like [How do I reload the page without the query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241851/in-javascript-how-do-i-reload-the-page-without-the-query-parameters) (looks like using `window.pathname` is the cleanest solution)

Comment: This wouldn't work for the general case:
`www.example.com/some/other/stuff/categoryN?foo`

Comment: Thanks, man. But what I want to know is if there is some way that I don't need to hardcoded the relative url and it just goes to the url without everything after question mark?

Comment: @Noyo what are you talking about? Why not?

Comment: As @chaonextdoor commented, (s)he(?) wants a general solution without having to hardcode the path part. My solution fixes this with a little javascript.

Comment: ah, yes, that is true. Except in that case, this question is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you should consider when writing relative URLs is the use of a base element.  Base elements allow you to define the the context for a relative URL path.

Information about using the base element: [Click Here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/base)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `href="../category1/"`

Answer (score -1):

As has been noted, if you know the pathname and want to hardcode it into the markup, you can just specify the relative path:

`<a title="Go to Category 1" href="/category1">Category 1</a>`

Otherwise, if you want a dynamic solution or don't want to hardcode the path, you can use javascript to get rid of the query parameters and make clicking the link do a redirect:

`<a href="#" title="Return to main category page" onclick="window.location.href = window.location.pathname; return false;">Category N</a>`

(For more information on `window.location` and its properties, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.location#Properties .)