# Javascript refresh page without ?var=x

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like a script that refreshes a page when required and also strips out anything after and including the ? in the url.

Is this possible with javascript?

Comment: check if this works :- 
 
`var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var newlocation = pathname.split(?)[0];
window.location.href = newlocation;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Javascript, how do I reload the page without the query parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241851/in-javascript-how-do-i-reload-the-page-without-the-query-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do

```
window.location = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
```

or

```
window.location = window.location.pathname;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

```
var url = window.location.href.replace(/\?.*/g,"");
```

OR just use:

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
```