# How do I reload a page without one query parameter?

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have a URL like:

```
www.domain.com/index.jsp?queryParam1=true&queryParam2=false&queryParam3=12
```

How would I remove just `queryParam2=false` from the string on page reload?

I took a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241851/in-javascript-how-do-i-reload-the-page-without-the-query-parameters) but it seems to remove all the query parameters.  I am in particular trying to do this when a user presses the "Reload this page" button on their browser or they are using the associated hotkey.

Comment: Why you don't use `str.replace("queryParam2=false", "")`?

Comment: Do you want to remove parameter on page reload?

Comment: @Mohammad, yes - on reload

Comment: @Barmar Why you don't read question exacly and marked it as duplicate?

Comment: @Mohammad It's essentially the same. Once you know how to remove the query parameters, reloading the page with the updated URL should be obvious.

Comment: @Barmar Question is about changing parameter on page reload.

Comment: @Mohammad So you put the code in the event listener for clicking on the reload button.

Comment: @Barmar What is event listener of browser reload button?!!

Comment: @Mohammad AFAIK you can't catch that. I thought he meant a `<button>` in his HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
location = location.href.replace(/(\?|\&)(queryParam2=)([^&]*)/, '$1');
```

Comment: True, but you don't want to omit the ? or & check so not to match with other query strings like: (page?otherqueryParam2=foo&var=foo2) and (page?foo=queryParam2&var=foo2) ..etc

Comment: Ahh, good point. I'd use `\b` to check for a word boundary, but that works also.

Answer (score 0):

Use the regex `\bqueryParam2=false&?` to locate the query parameter, and optionally a trailing `&` if there are more parameters beyond it. If you want to remove `queryParam2` no matter what value it has, use the regex `\bqueryParam2[^&]*&?`.

```
redirectButton.onclick = function() {
    window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/\bqueryParam2=false&?/,"");
}
```

```js
var url = "www.domain.com/index.jsp?queryParam1=true&queryParam2=false&queryParam3=12";
url = url.replace(/\bqueryParam2=false&?/,"");
document.body.innerHTML = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet that would remove `queryParam2` from a string:

```
var url = "www.domain.com/index.jsp?queryParam1=true&queryParam2=false&queryParam3=12"

url.replace(/\queryParam2=(.*)&/, '');

// Produces:
// "www.domain.com/index.jsp?queryParam1=true&queryParam3=12"
```

Comment: This doesn't work if there's more than one `&` after `queryParam2` because `.*` will be greedy. You could use `.*?` or even better: `[^&]*`.