# Remove one of multiple parameters from URL AND refresh the page without removed parameter BUT with the other parameters

Tags: javascript, refresh

When I remove one parameter from a URL with javaScript, then call:

window.location.assign(newURL);

It doesn't refresh the page without the parameter. It does nothing. How do I refresh the page without the parameter?

EDIT:

I have 2 parameters. It properly refreshes the page with all parameters removed. But it doesn't refresh the page when I leave one of the perameters in the URL. That is my problem.

The URL is:

https://thedomainsample.net/tablet/thePage.html?parameter1=388617&parameter2=true

Here is my code:

```
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    const firstParameter = urlParams.get('parameter1');
    
    window.location = window.location.href.split("?")[0]+"?parameter1="+ firstParameter;
```

It basically removes the second parameter and tries to set the location to a URL with just the first parameter. It doesn't refresh the page, it does nothing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241851/how-do-i-reload-the-page-without-the-query-parameters - `window.location.href = window.location.pathname`

Comment: I have 2 parameters. It properly refreshes the page with all parameters removed. But it doesn't refresh the page when I leave one of the perameters in the URL. That is my problem.

Comment: Give us more code. Show us how you are removing the parameter.

Comment: So, debug  (step through) your code when you're using one parameter and see what's happening... we can't tell you.  We have no idea what your code is doing with parameters.

Comment: Just edited with my code