# Remove part of the link in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a button were people can click on to get redirected to a new url based on the current url.

```
/collection/?filter_kleur=grijs&query_type_kleur=or
```

I want everything after collection/ to be removed. What is the easiest way to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reload the page without the query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7241851/how-do-i-reload-the-page-without-the-query-parameters)

Comment: Hi Jip! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to add a [mre]!

Comment: Why can't you just *hard-code* the `href` attribute with `/collection/NAME` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the URL api.

```js
const url = new URL('https://test.be/collection/?filter_kleur=grijs&query_type_kleur=or');

const output = document.getElementById('output');
output.innerHTML = url.host + url.pathname;
```

```html
<output id="output"></output>
```